# Android SQLite Where not found

Tags: android, database, sqlite

my App save the modelname in a string. Than it read in a database to find the model. When the column not exist, the program should take the "NotListed" column. How can I do it?

My Code: I thought the cursor is null when the column not exist but it don't work.

```
String s = android.os.Build.MODEL;
    Cursor dataCursor = mDb.rawQuery
            ("SELECT * FROM Smartphone WHERE Model = '"+s+"'",null);
    if (dataCursor!=null)
            {
        dataCursor.moveToNext();
            }else {
     dataCursor = mDb.rawQuery
            ("SELECT * FROM Smartphone WHERE Model = 'NotListed'",null);
    dataCursor.moveToNext();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (dataCursor!=null)
   {
      if(dataCursor.getCount()!=0){
             dataCursor.moveToNext();
       }
      else {
         dataCursor = mDb.rawQuery
        ("SELECT * FROM Smartphone WHERE Model = 'NotListed'",null);
        dataCursor.moveToNext();
       }
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

The `Cursor` is never `null`, it will just contain 0 or more rows, or an exception is thrown.

Check the result of `moveToNext()` (or more canonically, `moveToFirst()`) whether the move succeeded i.e. there is at least 1 row.

Answer (score -1):

try it ::::---->>>

dataCursor=mDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Smartphone WHERE Model = "+ "NotListed", null);